# Android Studio; get image in drawable through url

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, canvas, android-studio

I want to image in run time through url in android studio..

For example in eclipse find the image through url in that way..

in that case eclipse has provide that code. I have pass image name in imagename and then get image in drawable.

```
   companyLogo.setImageResource(getResourse.getIdentifier
  ("com.example.moneymanagement:drawable/"+imagename,null,null));
```

how to find that case in android studio.. this code has not accepted in android studio. how to find image in run time

Comment: In your AndroidManifest, it has your package as: `<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.moneymanagement">`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work Perfect but when you call `drawable` image then you Conform the package name should be correct. It work Perfect.

```
 companyLogo.setImageResource(getResourse.getIdentifier
 ("com.example.moneymanagement:drawable/"+imagename,null,null));
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

check the `getIdentifier(...)` method signature.

[image]

`String uri="@drawable/" + imageName;
 ivImage.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName()));`

Comment: my code is------                                                                                                                                     String url="ic_launcher.png";
       int res= getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/"+url, null, getPackageName());                                                                                                     but it is not get the image.

Comment: thanks but if my image in sub folder in drawable then do not read..   means i want to read "@drawable/grey/"+url"

Answer (score 0):

Java is Java.. it doesn't matter whether it is compiled by Android Studio or Eclipse. In your case, I think you have `getResource.getIdentifier` but you should use `getResources().getIdentifier(...)`

Comment: my code is----------                                                                                                                                     String url="ic_launcher.png";
       int res= getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/"+url, null, getPackageName()); --------------------                                                                                                    but it is not get the image.